# The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument and utils

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add one alert box for language selection, but couldn't figure out the builder error I'm facing.
it was working fine with flutter older version but not with 2.2.3 version of flutter
Thanks

for the help
Looking forward for the solution

> The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
> Undefined name 'Utils'.

[image: this three error i m getting]

```dart
   Future <void> _languageCheck() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final firstRun = prefs.getBool("firstRunLanguage");
    (firstRun ?? false)
        ? () {}
        : await showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        child: AlertDialog(content: LanguageDialog()));
    await prefs.setBool('firstRunLanguage', true);
  }
```

**Widget**

```dart
class LanguageDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LanguageDialogState createState() => _LanguageDialogState();
}

class _LanguageDialogState extends State<LanguageDialog> {
  var langCode = "en";

  void getLanguage() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    langCode = prefs.getString("language") ?? kAdvanceConfig['DefaultLanguage'];
    printLog("langCode-->$langCode");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLanguage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> languages = Utils.getLanguagesList(context);
    for (var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++) {
      // if (langCode == languages[i]["code"]) {
      //   print(languages[i]["code"]);
      // }
      list.add(
        ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset(
            languages[i]["icon"],
            width: 30,
            height: 20,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          title: Text(languages[i]["name"]),
          trailing: langCode == languages[i]["code"]
              ? const Icon(
            Icons.radio_button_checked,
            color: Colors.teal,
          )
              : const Icon(
            Icons.radio_button_off,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          onTap: () async {
            setState(() {
              langCode = languages[i]["code"];
            });
            await Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false)
                .changeLanguage(languages[i]["code"], context);
          },
        ),
      );
      if (i < languages.length - 1) {
        list.add(
          Divider(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
            height: 1.0,
            indent: 75,
            //endIndent: 20,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ...list,
          const LinearProgressIndicator(),
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text("OK")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`showDialog` doesn't have `child`, use its `builder` like

```dart
     await showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => // here 
             AlertDialog(content: LanguageDialog()))
```

More on [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Comment: thank you and one more what's wrong with  Utils.getLanguagesList

Comment: I think that's a class, or using others packages,  can you include what is `Utils` in your case?

Comment: List<Map<String, dynamic>>? languages = getLanguages(); sorted out this was the main culprit

Comment: Is it coming from a separate class?  `getLanguages();` can you include the class and how `getLanguages()` is named on `Utils` class on question.

Comment: yes it separate class coming from some other file

Comment: Can you include how you are importing that file, also that method.

Answer (score 1):

You used `showDialog()` method which has a required parameter caller `builder` so you must provide the `builder` argument so try like below

```
Future <void> _languageCheck(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final firstRun = prefs.getBool("firstRunLanguage");
    (firstRun ?? false)
        ? () {}
        : await showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        /// this builder parameter is required
        builder:(context) => AlertDialog(content: LanguageDialog()));
    await prefs.setBool('firstRunLanguage', true);
  }
```